# Get control under mouse on GUI with WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a `LayeredWindow` GUI that contains some child's and all of them contains the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` style.

The style is used to be able to remove their background.

When i move the mouse over the GUI only the `LayeredWindow` receives the message `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.

I tried calling [ChildWindowFromPointEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-childwindowfrompointex?redirectedfrom=MSDN) using the `XY` pos got from the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` `lParam`
to detect the control being hovered, but the API didn't recognize any of the controls belonging to the child GUI's.

Docs says:

> The search is restricted to immediate child windows. Grandchildren and deeper descendants are not searched.

The other option i tried was [EnumChildWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows) and compare each control rect to the XY position of the message, this method is using around 1% of CPU only from moving the mouse.

I wonder if there's any 'better' option?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc:[Layered Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows)

> Hit testing of a layered window is based on the shape and transparency
> of the window. This means that the areas of the window that are
> color-keyed or whose alpha value is zero will let the mouse messages
> through. However, if the layered window has the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
> extended window style, the shape of the layered window will be ignored
> and the mouse events will be passed to other windows underneath the
> layered window.

You could try to use [GetCursorPos function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos) to get the position of the mouse cursor, in screen coordinates.

Comment: And how to get the control under the cursorpos?

Comment: You could handle window's [WM_NCHITTEST message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in order to be able to let system know that particular position is transparent, in which case you return `HTTRANSPARENT`.